# How can I write HFS partitions?

Tags: 12.04, mac

I have an iMac Late 2009 with OS X Lion and Ubuntu 12.04. I want to exchange files between Mac and Linux without creating a partition or using a USB, so, the question is simple: which app should I have for writing in my HFS(+) partition?

I tried to disable journaling **lots** of times, saying it was done, but it doesn't seems to work... :/

Comment: To people considering closing this question: The OP has solved the problem and the OP's solution has been [posted as an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/175100/22949), so this question should **not** be closed as *too localized*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**User Solved in Edit:**

> I just needed to modify the file permissions

Comment: It would be great if we know the exact details

Comment: @Anwar It's easy: the HD's file permissions disallowed me to read/write the Mac files, so I just gave r/w permissions to every folder and file which I use frequently.

Comment: @espectalll123 can you edit in the information or create your own answer to show the steps so you can get credit for solving your question.